# Pytest is returning a fixture error because it can't find a method argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Context:
I am using the page object model for selenium/pytest UI tests

Problem:
I am returning a fixture error because pytest is claiming that the arguments are not available within the fixture.

My understanding is that Pytest doesn't rely on a fixture if my method arguments are declared within my class. I have this particular test inherit from where this was defined so I don't know why I am seeing this error.

Test:

```
import pytest
from pages import foo_page
import inspect

class TestDamageModal():

    def test_damage_modal(self, driver):
        return foo_page.FooPage(driver)

    def test_foo_year(self, year):
        year.with_("1999")
```

Here's a snippet from "foo_page.py" that should cover the usage of "year" above:

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self._visit(foo")

def with_(self, year):
    self._click(self._year_input)
    self._type(self._year_input, year)
```

Error:

```
    def test_foo_year(self, year):
E       fixture 'year' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, driver, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, worker_id
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Comment: You're confusing the formal parameter to `with_` named `year` with the formal parameter to `test_foo_year` with the same name.

Comment: So actually it seems that I had to add a fixture to the test. I updated the following: 

@pytest.fixture
def year(self, driver):
    return seller_page.SellerPage(driver)

def test_seller_year(self, year):
    year.with_("1999")

The test is now passing. My problem is that if I want to use different arguments throughout the test will I need to define this within the above fixture?

e.g.

def year(self, driver)

def month(self, driver)

I am not understanding this portion.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `pytest`, but keep in mind that *you* are not directly calling the test functions; the test runner needs to be supplied with the value(s) to pass to each `test_*` function.